# Using Past tense words

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrase-usage, lyrics

This is a chorus of a song called "Exercises in Futility VI" by a band called [Mgła](https://www.metal-archives.com/albums/Mg%C5%82a/Exercises_in_Futility/527726).

> Self crucified - missed the right tree.
>  Tore the wrong eye
>   out.
>  The hissing of hellfire.
>  Self crucified - missed the
>   right tree.
>  For this I've gained a victory.
>  I burn as I
>   ought to.

As we see, almost all words are in Past tense (Self crucified, missed, Tore and gained). It appears the author is talking about past events. However, there is an odd line which is not.

> I burn as I ought to.

My opinion is that the use of the phrase "I burn as I ought to." might be wrong. It should be "I burned as I ought to." to fit the whole paragraph and because all of it appears to already have happened.

My questions are:

- Am I correct? Is this line wrongly phrased?
- If I am wrong and this is indeed valid english, what does the line mean? Why is it in present tense?

Comment: This is seemingly a request to help proofread someone else's text. This is a thing that we do not do. Also, interpretation requests (criticism, discussion, analysis, and divining the author’s intent) are out of scope and may be removed. This applies to all English texts and utterances, including (but not limited to) song lyrics, poetry, and legal documents. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”.

Comment: If there is an unstated specific concern about the accepted patterns of English, such as “What does (word) mean in context?” or “How does (grammar or punctuation rule) apply in context?” you can ask that question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only see one reasonable explanation: the past-tense verbs are in the past tense because they refer to things in the past, and the present-tense verb is in the present tense because it refers to a thing in the present. The singer is saying that because of those *past* events, they *currently* "burn as they ought to".

This interpretation is reinforced by the fact that "I've gained a victory" is in the present perfect rather than the simple past. The use of the present perfect in "I've gained a victory" implies that the speaker is currently still benefiting from the victory. If the benefit were come and gone, then the speaker would have said "I gained a victory".

(Apparently, the "benefit" in this case is that the speaker is burning. That doesn't make much sense, but rock and metal lyrics don't usually make much sense anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

In the penultimate line, "I've gained" is *present perfect* -- not *past tense*.  The final line is *habitual*.  It seems only natural to proceed from past to present as the lyrics progress.